# ZFS vdev naming?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, zfs

I have no idea what is the rationale behind naming the vdev (virtual devices) used while creating zfs pools in Solaris. Suppose, I have a disk c4d0, what is meant by c4d0p0 and c4d0s0? And, how would I know what to use with ZFS commands. I am terribly confused since I keep getting "invalid vdev specified". Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

c4d0s0 = controller 4, disk 0, slice 0

Answer (score 3):

If you want the full disk to be used by ZFS you would want to use the main disk name, c4d0 in your case.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good article: ["How Solaris disk device names work"](http://initialprogramload.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-solaris-disk-device-names-work.html).

This might help.

Answer (score 1):

[ZFS Best Practices Guide](http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/ZFS_Best_Practices_Guide) recommends using whole disk for production setup - so do what X-Istence said - use c4d0 without the slice number. With ZFs you can throw away all you know about partitioning - they are so 1990s!